Screen monitor resolution problem
I use Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS.
My original screen monitor passed away last week. So, I had to change it, an now I've been using a smart TV set, with a native resolution of 1360 by 768 pixels.
I have a problem with some apps (like the LSP Stereo Multiband Compressor Plugin) that need more than 768 pixels of vertical screen size (I cannot see the lower parts of those apps, because the app window exceeds the vertical monitor size).
So, I need help to fix it, if it can be fixed.
Is there some way to decrease the app panel size?
Or... Is there a way to scroll it up and down? ???
